# How to convert power law transformed array to image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to convert a modified **image array** to an **actual image** (write it/extract it in other words). I've searched here on **stackoverflow** a lot but I couldn't find a solution.

I am using Python 3, with  `cv2`  library

Here is what I've tried:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
 
im = cv2.imread('Trendy_Funny_Saying_1.jpg')
im = im/255.0
im_power_law_transformation = cv2.pow(im, 1.6) # THIS ONE SHOULD BE WROTE TO A NEW IMAGE
npa = np.asarray(im_power_law_transformation, dtype=np.float32)
cv2.imwrite('modified.jpg', npa)
```

and the only result every time I get is a black image, which is not what I want and there's still something wrong in my code.

Some help please, I'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read a JPEG, you are going to get integers in the range 0..255 which will become floats in the range 0..1 when you divide by 255.0

If you raise these to the power 1.6, you will have floats in the range 0..1.

You can't write floats to a JPEG, so you have a couple of choices:

- write to a TIFF which can store floats, i.e. `cv2.imwrite('result.tif', npa)`, or
- convert to integers in range 0..255 and save as JPEG, i.e. `cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', (npa*255).astype(np.uint8))`

In general, it's a good idea to check the `dtype` and range of your image data before writing, i.e.

```
print(npa.dtype, npa.min(), npa.max())
```